# Explanation of shorthand argument list code snippet Swift

Tags: swift

I want to understand this piece of code. I am new to Swift. This code snippet is confusing to me. Thanks in advance.

```
let query = SomeClass.someMethod{ $0
    .person{ $0
        .name()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is that you don't understand and what you do understand? Is there anything more to this code?

Comment: It would perhaps be clearer if you didn't separate `$0` from the method call, i.e `$0.person { ... }` & `$0.name()`.

Answer (score 0):

$0 is shorthand argument name. Swift automatically provides shorthand argument names to inline closures, which can be used to refer to the values of the closure’s arguments by the names $0, $1, $2, and so on.

So you can rewrite this method:

```
let query = SomeClass.someMethod { parameter in
    parameter.person{ 
        parameter.name()
    }
}
```

parameter is a parameter that pass in closure